# How to append text with paste?

Tags: copy-paste

In android many times I just want to paste in text after the current text. But Android won't offer the paste context unless I select text. This means I have to overwrite text I want or insert a garbage word that will get pasted over. How do I just append the text in the clipboard to the current text?

For example if I long press after the entered text android selects the last set of chars and i have tonpaste over it.
[image: long press after text]

Answer (score 0):

On Android, to paste text, all you have to do, is long press anywhere after the last words that are displayed at the moment. This will bring up a few options, and one of them will be *paste* press on that, and the text will appear where you want it to.

In the screenshot below, if you want to paste something after the word *here* all you have to do, is long press where the red circle is (or anywhere along the line). This can get tricky in a situation where you want to paste between words.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I added a pictures that shows what happens when I long press in the box after the entered text.

Comment: @jerermy that's real strange. It doesn't happen by me. Are you actually long pressing far away from the question mark?

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207777/how-to-paste-text-between-existing-words?rq=1