# How to paste text between existing words?

Tags: text-input, copy-paste

When writing on Android, such as YouTube comments, I sometimes need to change word orders or paste words. Cutting an existing word is easy: just long press the word and then select "Cut". But I have been having difficulties in pasting the test at the right position.

For example, let's say that I have copied "vicious" in the clipboard, and I want to paste it into an existing sentence "I saw a dog." between "a" and "dog". If I try to long-press the space between "a" and "dog", the word "dog" gets selected. I can then select "Paste", but then the current selection gets replaced by it, which is not what I want. I cannot find anyway to past a word without selecting anything.

I am using Gboard (Google Keyboard).

Comment: Put some soaces between the words, then long-press and paste.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. And for the Irfan View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the Google symbol in the top left of Gboard.

[image: Gboard menu]

2. Select the `-I-`.

[image: Gboard other menu]

3. Use the arrows to move the cursor where you want to paste the word. Select paste.